# React Set State inside a test for a component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

I am trying to write tests for my ReCaptcha component. I have got a conditional statement that if the Site Key is true/has a value, then the ReCaptcha is returned. This is the useState.

```
Const [reCaptchaKey, setReCaptchaKey] = useState(null);
```

This is an example of the code that I am trying to test. There are no props that are taken into the component that have a bearing on the test.

```
{recaptchaKey && (
  <div>
    <ReCAPTCHA ....
  </div>
  )}
```

This is what I have so far.

```
test('No error', async () => {
  const recaptchaKey = 'key123';
  const setRecaptchaKey = () => {return recaptchaKey};
  const component = shallow(
  <ReCaptcha recaptchaKey={recaptchaKey} 
    setRecaptchaKey={setRecaptchaKey} /> 
  );
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

The above code I know isn't working, I have tried using jest.fn() although I reckon I haven't used it correctly. I should probably say the that if I log out the key it is returning 'null' so I could just do with a hand with working out how to set that to true for example.

Comment: I think shallow mounting does not allow to modify the state. I might be wrong though. Try using the regular mount function instead

Comment: @szczocik when I do that I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined". This is what its changed to: "const component = mount(
      <ReCaptcha" and don't worry i have imported it

Comment: Can you create a minimum reproducible example on codesandbox? It might be easier to see what's going on.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-allen-on90sh?file=/src/App.js Has that worked for you?

Comment: So you are passing two props to your ReCaptcha component. How do you assign them? Do you use them at all? Wouldn't it work if you would assign the passed recaptchaKey to the state, like so: ```Const [reCaptchaKey, setReCaptchaKey] = useState(props.recaptchaKey);```

Comment: That was just my attempt to see if that would get them into the component. The method that sets the key is in the component. It is run by a useEffect. There is 2 props but they are nothing to do with the ReCaptcha

Comment: I mean, you could expose the recaptchaKey as an optional prop in order to use it for testing. I'm not sure if that's the best approach for it, but that way you can easily manage the state by passing a value that will be assigned directly to the state and test it with shallow mount